# jQuery-Ajax autoComplete for Spring MVC not responding

Tags: spring, jquery, spring-mvc, jquery-autocomplete

i am trying to use autocomplete with the help of ajax in my Spring MVC application. i had refered the [this](http://www.spinachsoftware.com/blog/?p=160). But there are some issues in it. please guide me..

my script is like..

```
    <script>

$(function() {
    $( "#bName" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "getBatchNames.jav",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                        term: request.term
                      },
                success: function( data ) {                 
                    response( $.map( data.batchNameList, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.pinMasterBatchName,
                            value: item.pinMasterBatchName
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    });
});

</script>
....
<tr>
                            <td width="95%">
                            <div class="ui-widget">
                                <label style="width:35%;">Batch Name</label>
                                <form:input path="pinMasterBatchName" id="bName" class="txtBox"/>
                               </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

The call is going to the controller and its returning the Map>.. I will describe what i had done..

in controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getBatchNames.jav", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, List<PinMasterData>> getZipcodes()
    {

        System.out.println("helloooo");
        List<PinMasterData> batchNameList = pinService.ListBatchesUnderClient(45);
        Map<String, List<PinMasterData>> pinMap = new HashMap<String, List<PinMasterData>>();
        pinMap.put("batchNameList", batchNameList);
        return pinMap;
    }
```

And in my model class is class is like

```
public class PinMasterData 
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column ( name = "Id" )
    private Integer Id;

    @Column ( name = "BatchName" )
    private String pinMasterBatchName;

    @Column ( name = "Prefix" )
    private String Prefix;
```

Actually the call is going to the controller and its returning the list back. But after that the jsp page is not showing the list beneath the text field. What is the problem? please guide me..
Thanks in advance

Edit..

```
success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.batchNameList, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.pinMasterBatchName,
                            value: item.pinMasterBatchName
                        };
                    }));
                            alert("hai");
                }
            });
```

i had tried this(for checking whether call backs to ajax). But its not showing that alert box too..

Answer (score 0):

Is the control reaching the success callback ? You could verify that putting a debugger statement like below.

```
success: function( data ) {                 
        response( $.map( data.batchNameList, function( item ) {
            return {
                label: item.pinMasterBatchName,
                value: item.pinMasterBatchName
};
```

Chances are it is not. Try using complete Callback. This way you will know what status is being returned. jQuery does not consider the ajax call a success if there is a json parse error.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Look for `complete(jqXHR, textStatus)`

**Edit**

Replace the succcess with this. The execution should stop at the debugger provided your call to spring has returned. If it has not returned I would look at the server logs and see if the call response failed for some reason. If it does return then I would look at the data object, it should contain a status of the response ( Note; I don't rememeber the exact key name. ). Look at the response text and copy the responseText and put it in http://www.jsonlint.com and see that its a valid json. ( Hope you are familar with firebug for debugging in firefox ).

```
complete: function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {                 
        debugger;
        response( $.map( data.batchNameList, function( item ) {
            return {
                label: item.pinMasterBatchName,
                value: item.pinMasterBatchName
};
```

Comment: i had given an alert inside the success. But its also not displaying. I think its something about the response(ie with json), for im getting called to the controller. i am really new to this ajax. So please guide me